# Selecting table after selected one

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse an HTML page using [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) and want to select the next table element after the one I currently have selected.

I'm selecting the table just before the one I want using this.

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='KnownClass']"))
```

example html

```
<table class="KnownClass"> … </table>
<!-- other html that does not contain tables here -->
<table> … </table> <!-- want to select this table -->
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
foreach (var table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='KnownClass']/following-sibling::table[1]"))
{
    ...
}
```